# How can take input for extrnal platform ie.., boiler plate code for plain javascript

Tags: javascript, boilerplate

```
var stdin = process.openStdin();
stdin.addListener("data",function (d) {

})
```

**Sample input**:

```
1
5
```

I want take this input in my code. I can't able to write boiler plate code please help me

Comment: I'm guessing you'll need _addListener_ first. Spelling is very important with code.

Comment: Yeah I'm correct it but how can take input in my code

Comment: So what you want to know is how to monitor the StdOut of an external process from inside JavaScript?